# How to create a localization Bounding Box form Densenet output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I want something simmilar to a Class Activation Map (e.g. https://github.com/nickbiso/Keras-Class-Activation-Map). In the class activation map, a heatmap of some sort is created around some areas of the input image for a specific predicted value of an output neuron. Instead of a heatmap, I want a bounding box around that area of the input image!
I'm using python3 and Keras.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @AmitBaranes Mostly Google search ;). All I found was other models and networks to do this localization and bounding box. But I need to use my own Densenet which is trained on my custom dataset. The heatmap code pretty much works by getting the .h5 file of the trained model, getting an input image, performing prediction on that image, and then generating a heatmap over the input image based on the prediction. I need something like this, but instead of the heatmap, a bounding box.